# Spark (scala) dataframes - Return list of words from a set that are found in a given string

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using a UDF function to apply to a column of strings in a spark dataframe which iterates over a `words` set of words, and finds if the given column string contains any of the words from the set (see below):

```
udf { (s: String) => words.value.exists(word => s.contains(word)) }
```

How would I need to alter this function so that it returns a list of all the items in the `words` set which are found in the string?

I have tried using `when` and `otherwise`:

```
udf { (s: String) => when(words.value.exists(word => s.contains(word)), word).otherwise(null) }
```

But i get a `type mismatch`, and anyway, I think this would only return the first match. I'm just learning scala and spark, so any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument passed to the `udf` function you're using here should be a plain Scala function - any use of SQL functions like `when` would return a `Column` object, which is not the intended return type of these functions (they should return types supported as data types in Spark DataFrames - primitives, arrays, maps, case classes etc.).

So, the implementation would simply be:

```
udf { (s: String) => words.value.filter(word => s.contains(word)) }
```

This creates a UDF with input type `String` and outpur type `Seq[String]`, which means the resulting column would be ab `Array` column.

For example:

```
val words = sc.broadcast(Seq("aaa", "bbb"))
val udf1 = udf { (s: String) => words.value.filter(word => s.contains(word)) }

Seq("aaabbbb", "bbb", "aabb").toDF("word").select(udf1($"word")).show()
// +----------+
// | UDF(word)|
// +----------+
// |[aaa, bbb]|
// |     [bbb]|
// |        []|
// +----------+
```

Comment: Thanks @Tzach - that sounds almost too easy to be true. I just tried running this and get an error (`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] is not supported`). Does it matter that my `words` is an immutable set (which is being broadcast)?

Comment: Yes, if `words` is a `Set[String]`, the return type of the UDF becomes `Set[String]` too - which isn't a supported DataFrame type. To resolve this - simply convert the result to `Seq`: `udf { (s: String) => words.value.filter(word => s.contains(word)).toSeq }`